# <a> tags positioned differently when containing text

Tags: html, css

I'm having a weird issue that I can't figure out. I have a div that contains anchor tags that get positioned differently depending on if they have text in them.

What I'm trying to do is have a simple bar graph with numbers shown inside the bar, with the numbers aligned on the bottom. In the below example, the top graph has the bars aligned to the bottom correctly, but in the bottom graph, as soon as I add the numbers, it flips to the top. Any ideas whats going on and how I can fix (or a better way to do this)?

http://jsfiddle.net/dKM3T/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .graph {
                width: 650px;
            }
            .graph .bar {
                width: 20px;
                margin: 1px;
                display: inline-block;
                background: #666;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="graph">
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:40px" data-index="1"></a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:20px" data-index="2"></a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:30px" data-index="3"></a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:20px" data-index="4"></a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:12px" data-index="5"></a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:32px" data-index="6"></a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:34px" data-index="7"></a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:12px" data-index="8"></a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:40px" data-index="9"></a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:20px" data-index="10"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="graph">
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:40px" data-index="1">40</a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:20px" data-index="2">20</a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:30px" data-index="3">30</a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:20px" data-index="4">20</a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:12px" data-index="5">12</a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:32px" data-index="6">32</a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:34px" data-index="7">34</a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:12px" data-index="8">12</a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:40px" data-index="9">40</a>
            <a href="#" class="bar" style="height:20px" data-index="10">20</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .graph {
            width: 650px;
        }
        .graph .bar {
            vertical-align: bottom;
            width: 20px;
            margin: 1px;
            display: inline-block;
            background: #666;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
```

The numbers still show at the top of the graph, but the graph is no longer flipped. If you want the numbers to display at the bottom, you might need to take a different approach than the one you have here.

Comment: thanks! any idea why vertical-align is needed when the <a> has content, and not needed when the <a> is blank?

Comment: Possibly because vertical-align applies to text, so when the `<a>` doesn't have text, the browser doesn't register the need to vertically align it (just a guess unfortunately)

Comment: Erm, not really. `vertical-align` applies to the `inline` and `inline-block` elements themselves, in this case the `a` tag. There's a nice look at `vertical-align` at http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/ if you want to learn more about what's happening there.

Comment: @ultranaut - actually, that article does not even come close to explaining what's happening in this instance.

Comment: @poops - What's happening is that the way `vertical-align:baseline` is resolved changes when content is added to inline-block boxes. When there is text, the box is aligned to the baseline of the box contents, i.e. the baseline of the text. Notice how the text in each box lines up. But when there is no content, the box has no baseline, so it can't be aligned accordingly. To cope with this, a completely different rule kicks in where the inline-block box itself is placed with its bottom on the baseline.